# Laravel Validation Rule array not working

Tags: php, laravel, validationrule

I tried to put all the validation rules to my database and put it to array
why is not working when you put it in array?

```
$data = model::where('page','post.create')->get();
        foreach($data as $value){
          $Rules[] = array($value->post_name => $value->validation);
        }

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [$Rules]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the Laravel documentation properly: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation

The mistake is in your 2nd argument in `Validator::make`, you must pass an array with `'field' => 'validation_rule'` pairs. E.g.

```
[
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required'
]
```

This code `$Rules[] = array($value->post_name => $value->validation);` will automatically append numeric array like for example like this:

```
[
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255'
],
[
    'body' => 'required'
]
```

And this is not what you want. You may also try to learn debugging my friend. Try to check the value of `$Rules` by running `dd($Rules);`.
So the correct syntax is this:

```
$data = model::where('page','post.create')->get();
foreach($data as $value){
    $Rules[$value->post_name] = $value->validation;
}

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $Rules);
```

Comment: I tried to erase the braces but the error returns to this
The 0 field is required

Comment: I get the basic part. but i want to tried if the dynamic validation will work. because in my input its customize too when i deactivated some input the static validation will remain to it

Comment: Did my answer solve your question? Try doing the code I provided on the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = model::where('page','post.create')->get();
        foreach($data as $value){
          $Rules[] = array($value['post_name'] => $value['validation']);
        }

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $Rules);
```

I think you should give the variable name inside array in line 3 and for using array `$Rules` you should not give the name inside square bracquet in line 5.

Comment: I already erase the bracket but it gives me this error message 
The 0 field is required

Comment: can you paste the error message here?. did you edited the $Rules[] inside foreach?

Comment: that is error in message bag . in the usual error it turns to 
The :attribute name is required
but it gives number i cant determine on what happens to the rule

Comment: var_dump($data); and paste the result here

Comment: array(1) { ["firstname"]=> string(7) "required" }